# Why does this comparison of strings work?

Tags: string, python-3.x

I seem to be missing something really obvious over here, but why does the given piece of code work?

```
n=int(input())
for i in range(n):
    for i in range(4):
        team, score=input().split(" ")
        if team[0]=="B":
            b=score
        elif team[0]=="R":
            r=score
        elif team[0]=="E":
            e=score
        elif team[0]=="M":
            m=score
    if b>e and m>r:
        print("Barcelona")
    else:
        print("RealMadrid")
```

The last if-else clause should throw an error, shouldn't it?(Since I am comparing b and e which are both strings)

What am I missing over here?

Comment: you should use int(b) > int(e) and int(m) > int(r) if you want int comparison

Comment: yeah ik, but was surprised to see this one work

Comment: yes, it is use to sort lists when you do a_list.sort() it uses those comparators

Comment: Note that the code as-is only works when the scores are single-digit, which admittedly is common in soccer. If you have 17 and 2 as scores, the ordering will be wrong unless you convert to int.

Answer (score 3):

Python performs string comparison using lexicographical ordering.

`<` checks the alphabetical ordering of the strings.